# Android: generate Drawable having resource image and Color

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-glide, android-color

I'm using Glide to load image from url and need to have a placeholder which is generated with a transparent pattern stored as a resource and a random background color. Glide allows using Drawable as a placeholder.
I have a transparent drawable resource
`int resId = R.drawable.placeholder;` and have `Color randomColor = generateRandomColor();`
How can I create a Drawable which is created in combination of resource and background random color,  smth. like `Drawable d = resId + randomColor;` ?
To have as a result:

```
Glide.with(getActivity).load(imageUl)
         .asBitmap().placeholder(d)
         .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method `setColorFilter` of Drawable

So the code will be like:

```
Drawable drawable = getDrawable(resourceId);
drawable.setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

Glide.with(getActivity).load(imageUl)
         .asBitmap().placeholder(drawable)
         .into(imageView);
```

PorterDuff has a lot of [modes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode.html), choose the one that's right for you